# powershell get-aduser extensionattribute12

Tags: powershell, properties, active-directory

```
$name="d4rkcell"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$Name)" -Properties extensionAttribute12
```

I am using the above code but the result shows more than just extensionAttribute12 it shows other information such as:

```
DistinguishedName    : CN=d4rkcell,OU=Users,...DC=co,DC=uk
Enabled              : True
extensionAttribute12 : \\path\to\a\share
GivenName            : Joe
Name                 : U0023883
ObjectClass          : user
ObjectGUID           : a0562e97-cb58-463b-bae6-8e0087fa494b
SamAccountName       : d4rkcell
SID                  : S-1-5-21-1004336368-1374586140-1801574631-62475
Surname              : Bloggs
UserPrincipalName    : J.Bloggs@....co.uk
```

I would ideally just want the value stored in extensionAttribute12, can anyone help me here or help me split this string ? Bit stuck, help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Properties` parameter of `Get-ADUser` seems a little misleading.  According to its [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx):

> Properties
>
> Specifies the properties of the output object to retrieve from the
>   server. Use this parameter to retrieve properties that are not
>   included in the default set.

So it seems any properties you specify will be returned in addition to the default set. If you want to further isolate a property from that set, you could try:

```
$name="d4rkcell"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$Name)" -Properties extensionAttribute12 |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty extensionAttribute12
```

If you always expect to get a single object containing properties, you could shorten this by wrapping the Get-ADUser command in parenthesis, and then appending the property name with a dot:

```
(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$Name)" -Properties extensionAttribute12).extensionAttribute12
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to select extensionAttribute12, for example:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$Name)" -Properties extensionAttribute12 | Select extensionAttribute12
```

Comment: The above (addition of | select extensionAttribute12) seems to narrow it down even further but the result still isn't as clean as I would like. it displays as 

    extensionAttribute12
    --------------------
    \\path\to\a\share

The reason i ask is I want to map a drive to this path stored in this AD attribute. I know the script to map drives i just need to store \\path\to\a\share in a variable that i can use.

Answer (score 0):

This showed up when I googled how to show all attributes, so I'll add this here. Note that's it's not very efficient, but I couldn't get a 1-15 loop to work.

```
get-aduser john -Properties * | select extensionattribute*
```

[image]